# Can I run socket and http test In parallel and change http request body depend last socket message used Jmeter

Tags: groovy, websocket, jmeter, load-testing

I need to write a load test for a web application which uses the WebSocket protocol for sending some server states to users and in parallel users send requests with data from this server state.
I need a socket client which will listen to the socket and update the current server state and at the same time need to send HTTP requests with data from the current state.

Can implement it on Apache JMeter? If yes may you know some useful articles (not about BlazeMeter parallel controller) or examples?
Or can you advise some tools which better for this target and which can generate a concurrent load of at least 20k users (currently use Jmeter cluster)? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One JMeter thread (virtual user) can only execute one [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) at a time, if you need to run 2 requests at the same moment you need to either need to use 2 different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or if you prefer to stay with 1 thread group you can use i.e. [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) so "even" users would run HTTP requests and "odd" WebSocket or vice versa.

If you need to pass data between threads (virtual users) either use [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Way with using samples ws and http one by one I tried to implement and as socket is a bidirectional stream as I understand a thread lost messages during make an http request and got lots of requests with the incorrect state. I will try something with socket client on groovy and  interthread communication